# Is there a device and interface orientation in Android (like in iOS)?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-orientation, android-screen

Is there a way to get the device orientation in Android even if the interface orientation remains the same? I turn the device 180 degrees, the UI is upside down. But I still want to be notified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set up an [OrientationEventListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/OrientationEventListener.html) in the `Activity` you want to be notified of changes in.

Then you will have to specify the desired [ScreenOrientation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#screen) in the manifest for that `Activity` to prevent the screen from rotating.